# Mysql doesn´t start after expending data-dir with simlink to another database

Tags: mysql, macos

I´ve installed mysql and it worked fine.

Now I´d liked to have the data of several databases in my dropbox. So I put symlinks in my mysql data dir.

```
sudo ln -s /Users/michaelbenker/Dropbox/geschaeft/softwareentwicklung/DB/testdatabase /usr/local/mysql/data/testdatabase
```

Now when I tried to restart mysql, I get the error

```
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file 
(/usr/local/mysql/data/Michaels-iMac-783.local.pid).
```

In my error file I found this entry

```
2017-05-26T11:29:12.067923Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error 
number 13 in a file operation.
2017-05-26T11:29:12.067928Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld 
does not have the access rights to the directory.
2017-05-26T11:29:12.067934Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: 
os_file_readdir_next_file() returned -1 in directory ./, crash recovery 
may have failed for some .ibd files!
2017-05-26T11:29:12.067963Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization 
aborted with error Generic error
2017-05-26T11:29:12.375057Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function 
returned error.
2017-05-26T11:29:12.375090Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a 
STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-05-26T11:29:12.375097Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2017-05-26T11:29:12.375100Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

So I tried several things to change the permission to my Dropbox data-dir

- I tried to change the owner to mysql (tried also _mysql)
- I tried to change the group to mysql (tried also _mysql)
- I tried to change the chmod to 777

Nothing helped.

I did the same on my MacBook and here everything worked fine.

Here the actual permissions on the Dropbox Dir

```
drwxrwxrwx@  5 _mysql         _mysql    170 26 Mai 13:02 DB
```

Comment: Use linux as your development platform instead? Or maybe better install Docker!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will also need to be able to change into the *parents* of the Dropbox directory, which implies a `+x` on each one.

Comment: The path to my Drobbox dir is `/Users/michaelbenker/Dropbox/geschaeft/softwareentwicklung/DB/`.
How can I set the permissions `+x`? Can you give me the Terminal command?

Comment: @MichaelBenker: I'm sure you can work out how to set a permission on a directory. It's pretty basic stuff. It would be better for you to perform some research than me just handing you a command.